# Как изменить параметр src?

Tags: php, html

Как изменить параметр src?
Есть картинка и кнопка. Когда человек нажимает на кнопку картинка должна измениться на другую. Наприпер с http://yandex.ru/blabla.png вот на эту http://google.ru/blabla.png

Comment: Мне кажется, имеет смысл полностью описать задачу.
Это из разряда "Как сменить болт?". Просто смени его...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делайте это при помощи javascript. И быстрее и проще.

```
document.getElementById('id_рисунка').src="new_src.png";
```

или на джиквери:

```
$('#id_рисунка').attr('src',"new_src.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

Да, [@knes](/users/2825/knes) прав. Но если уж так  надо на php и никаких других критериев в задаче не указано, то, например, так:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET[pic]) && $_GET[pic] == 1) {
    echo "<img src=http://yandex.ru/blabla.png><br>";
} else {
    echo "<img src=http://google.ru/blabla.png><br>";
}
 ?>
 <html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
<?php 
if (isset($_GET[pic]) && $_GET[pic] == 1) {
    echo "<a href=?pic=0>Сменить картинку на гугл</a>";
} else {
    echo "<a href=?pic=1>Сменить картинку на яндекс</a>";
}
 ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```